Living in France while having a B type visa in Switzerland on the way to be issued
I would like to ask if is possible to live in France while my B type of visa cards is still in process to be issued in Switzerland.
Does anyone has been in a similar situation? Or can recommend a reliable way to find a place in Switzerland? There is a lot, lot of scam on Facebook groups, and rents in the countries at the border are much more cheaper and available.

For completeness, what is your citizenship? And what is a ‘B type  of visa card’?

@Traveller Presumably the Swiss residence permit

Assuming you're an EU citizen (as the reference to the B permit would suggest), you are allowed to live in France but then you would probably look for a G permit instead. I don't think there is anything illegal about living in France or that it would jeopardize your application but ultimately the B permit is intended for people who reside in Switzerland and I would expect some complications down the line (e.g. with taxes or health insurance). All this is trickier for Swiss citizens or third-country citizens.

@Relaxed Switzerland uses the same letters (L, B, C, Ci) for both EU/EEA permits and for third-country permits.  The cards have a different appearance, but the letters are the same.  See https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/fr/home/themen/aufenthalt/biometr_auslaenderausweis.html

@phoog I thought so, they actually predate all the agreements with the EU, but couldn't find any reference to a B permit for non-EU citizens for some reason? Cf. the chapters “Ressortissants de l'UE/AELE” vs. “Non-ressortissants de l'UE/AELE” on the same website.

Oh I see I think I confused the list of “livrets”, which have always existed, and the new biometric cards.
